# What is the definition of first/last element in a poset?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

I have read the terms first element/last elements in the context of
a basic course in set theory.

When I learned about posets I didn't encounter those terms. I tried
looking up the definitions but I didn't find them.

Can someone please write down the definitions for first/last element
in a poset ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first element of a poset $\langle P,\le\rangle$ is simply the unique minimum element of $P$, if there is one: $p_0$ is the first element of $P$ if $p_0\le p$ for all $p\in P$. Similarly, the last element of $P$ is the unique maximum element of $P$, if there is one: $p_1$ is the last element of $P$ if $p\le p_1$ for all $p\in P$.

A poset need not have a first or last element.

Comment: Thanks Brian! I will accept when the system lets me (3 minutes)

Comment: @Belgi: As always, you’re welcome!

Answer (score 5):

If by "first" element you mean "an element preceding all others", then there need not be one (similarly for "last" element).

Consider the sets $\{1\}$, $\{2\}$, $\{3\}$, $\{1,2\}$, and $\{1,3\}$ ordered by inclusion. There is no first or last element, but there are three *minimal* elements (an element with no predecessor) and two *maximal* elements (an element with no successor).

In the case where there is an element preceding all others, it is generally called a *minimum* element. Similarly, the element that is preceded by all others is called a *maximum* element.

Comment: So $a$ is first if $a\leq b$ for all other elements $b$ ?

Comment: @Belgi That is a reasonable definition for "first", but I think "minimum" is a more common term for it.

Answer (score 5):

A poset need not have a first or last element.

- An element $a_1$ is *first* (the unique minimum) in a poset $P$ if $a_1 \le a\;\;\forall a \in P$.
- An element $a_n$ is *last* (the unique maximum) in a poset P if $a \le a_n \;\;\forall a \in P$.

(1) There may not be a "minimum" (first) *nor* "maximum" (last) element in a poset.

(2) You might have a unique minimum (first) element, *but no* maximum element (last) in a poset.

(3) Likewise, a poset may *not* have a minimum "first" element, but have a *maximum* ("last") element.

(4) And *if there is a unique minimum and a unique maximum element in the poset, then those are the **first** and **last** elements in the poset, respectively.*

---

**Exercise:** try to find an "example" poset that models/represents each of these four possibilities) (one per possibility)!

Comment: But I like yours